# Implementing a function which returns function definition as string

Tags: c++

I'm making a program in which a function, say `double f(double)`,  is defined.
I want to create a function(or a macro) `codeToStr(f)` which will return a `std::string`/`const char*` containing definition of the function `f`.
I believe that by using preprocessing directive something can be done but I can't figure out how.
Is there a way to do this besides using file IO and reading from the source file?

==
Reason for the question:
My university gave me the assignment to implement the "Trapezoidal rule" for numerical integration and they've asked us to hard-code the function f(x). After I submit the code, they will modify that function from the source code to test various cases. I'd like my output to have a way of displaying the function definition of the function that is going to be integrated. This is the reason why I want to implement `codeToStr`.

Comment: what do you need it for? Sometimes the simple solution is the way to go. If you need it for a single function I would just copy paste the definition of the function into a string

Comment: @idclev463035818 whenever I change the function definition, I'll have to change the strings each time. copy-pasting it everytime is not an option for me.

Comment: Starting point might be a `##` operator https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators to generate function itself and function returning it's contents.

Comment: @walnut No. I'm not looking specifically for that syntax. I don't mind wrapping the whole function definition in the macro.. but I still want that function to work as a function. I can't figure how to do that.

Comment: But why do you need the strings in the first place.  This sounds like an xy problem.

Comment: @g-m I've included the reason for converting code to string in the question.

Comment: @Sebastian I think you confuse function definition with its declaration. That Q&A is not about getting the whole definition of the function via a macro

Comment: @Sebastian that Q&A is about getting the name of the function, if I didnt miss something. I know that you can get the declaration with some hacks. But you cannot get the definition (unless you wrap the whole function inside a macro)

Comment: @Sebastian no OP here is asking for definition. Also in your answer you do not handle defnition but only declaration. I was commenting on that, but then realized that your answer can be applied to get also the definition

Comment: @idclev463035818 sorry, you are right, OP asking about definition. You wrote, That Q&A is *not* about getting the whole definition, which confused me. I will delete non-applying comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define real_stringify(s) #s
#define stringify(...) real_stringify(__VA_ARGS__)

#define MYFUNC double f(double d) { \
        return d*2; \
        }

MYFUNC

int main() {
        std::cout << f(5.5) << std::endl;
        std::string s = stringify(MYFUNC);
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

But this necessitate that the function is defined under the scope of the preprocessor. You can add more tricks to hide it as separating definition/declaration, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something like (untested):

```
#define xstr(a) str(a)
#define str(a) #a

#define FNDEF(ret,name,definition) \
    ret name definition \
    static char* name##_def xstr(ret) " " xstr(name) " " xstr(definition)

#define codeToStr(name) \
    (name##_def)
```

Then use

```
FNDEF(int, myfunction, (int param1, double param2), {do_something();})
```

in your .cpp file. And you can call

```
cout << codeToStr(myfunction) << endl;
```

anytime.